# Clojure httpkit spotify request

Tags: clojure, spotify, http-kit, clj-http

Following my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002912/clojure-spotify-user-authentication?noredirect=1#comment130667113_74002912), but to keep the code homogeneous I want to use httpkit to make requests instead of clj-http as I did before.

I have the following to try and receive my profile from the Spotify API:

```
(defn get-me [token]
  @(client/request
   {:url "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me"
    :method :get
    :headers {"Authorization" token
              "Accept" "application/json"
              "Content-Type" "application/json"}}))

(defn get-me-handler [req]
  (let [res (:token @TOKEN)]
  (if (= res "")
      {:status 404
       :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
       :body "Not logged in"}
      {:status 200
       :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
       :body (get-me (get (json/read-str res) "access_token"))})))
```

a long with a "localhost:{port}/me" route. When I access this route, I get back:

```
 {"status": 400, "message": "Only valid bearer authentication supported" }}"
```

As the error message. Does anyone know how to fix this in httpkit, as it is not a problem I had in clj-http?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule  any ideas? As you were so helpful before...

Comment: Shot in the dark: Should that not be `(str "Bearer " token)`?

Answer (score 0):

token in valid bearer authentication should start with "Bearer "

Comment: There's no information on the token string and this is speculation.  If you cannot be sure of your answer you need to clarify it in the comments.